# bash: process one file after the other

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a script that should take the first tar-file, execute `script.sh`, then the second tar-file and so on.
This is how `script.sh` looks like:

```
tarball=(`ls -a | cut -d "." -f 1`)
mkdir ./$tarball
tar -zxvf $tarball.tar -C ./$tarball
```

I execute `script.sh` with the following command:

```
for tarball in ./*.tar; do bash script.sh; done
```

but the assignment of the variable `tarball` only takes the first file and processes it (after the code posted above there are some `awk` commands that write some output to a file).

How do I script that after the first tar-file is taken, the second is taken and so on?

Comment: Because you don't pass anything to the script, you have the assignment in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this in your script or just put the while loop in your script and pipe whatever list you want into the script:

```
ls -1 | cut -d "." -f 1 |
    while read tarball
    do
        mkdir "$tarball"
        tar -zxvf "${tarball}.tar" -C ./"$tarball"
    done
```